# I am not able to get values from Contacts[i].getCustomFields("Organization ID");

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to get a custom Value from the Custom Field that is defined for most of our contacts, but we are not getting any data out of the script below, can any one figure out where I am going wrong with the script. below is the sample script I am using.

In the below script I am able to get the Primary email value, but the custom field value is blank for all the contacts even if the value is there in the contact.

```
function GetContactDir() {

var All_Contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();  

var email = new String();
var cust = new String();  
var Con_arr = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<All_Contacts.length; i++)
{

  email = "";
  email = All_Contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail();

  Con_arr = All_Contacts[i].getCustomFields("Organization ID");  //NOT WORKING

  if (!(email=="") && !(email==null) )
    Browser.msgBox(email + " **" + Con_arr[0] +  " ** " + String(i) ); 
}

}
```

Regards,
Saravana Kumar P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this :
 use

```
`Con_arr = All_Contacts[i].getCustomFields();`  //without the string value
```

and replace you line `Browser.msgBox ...`

with this :

```
if(!(Con_arr.length==0)){Logger.log(email + " **" +Con_arr[0].getLabel()+" = "+Con_arr[0].getValue() )};
```

Then look at the logger (Menu>View>log)

EDIT : here is the complete simplified test code :

```
function GetContactDir() {

var All_Contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();  

var email = '';
var cust = '';  
var Con_arr = new Array()

for (i=0; i<All_Contacts.length; i++){

  email = All_Contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail();

  Con_arr = All_Contacts[i].getCustomFields() ;  
  if (!(email=="") && !(email==null) )

    if(Con_arr.length>0){Logger.log(email + " **" +Con_arr[0].getLabel()+" = "+Con_arr[0].getValue() )}; 
}
}
```

EDIT2 : let's try to take the problem the other way, searching by custom field:
(please replace values by valid ones)

```
function GetContact_test() {
var All_Contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField('value of the field', 'name of the custom field');// note that the first term is a 'QUERY' so you don't need to give the entire ID, a single letter can bring results !
for(n=0;n<All_Contacts.length;++n){
Logger.log(n+'  '+All_Contacts[n].getFullName()); 
}
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your support extended. the problem I face is the Con_arr is returned with no Objects, because of which I am not able to use the .getLabel() & .getValue() functions. I am sure that We have Custom Fields added in most of our contacts, but still the object Con_arr is returning as an empty array. can you please explain why we observe this behavior  ??? :(

Comment: I just used your source that you have provided Serge

Comment: hmmm this is annoying... it's working for me... I'll try to findout how to debug this.

Comment: Thanks Serge, I shall also work on this and post if i find why this is behaving like this. But to confirm, for this function to work all we need is a custom field added to our each of the Contacts in Google Contacts and this should work fine then, am I correct Serge ??

Comment: Yes, you're right ... that's how I did too now please try EDIT2

Comment: Serge, this function is also returning no contacts in All_Contacts variable. I have replaces the "value of the field" & "name of the custom field". also added one more logger line before the loop to record the number of contacts that are returning, where 0 is logged in the logger :(..

Comment: Serge, one happy news, I tried the Edit2 in an another domain environment and I am getting results,they are working Positive. I now suspect the name of the Custom field. I have a space in that Custom Field name, but in this new environment the field name is continuous, let now create a new customer field in that old environment where it has failed and let you know the results

Comment: Serge, Yes I was correct, the name of the custom field was the prob, it had a space in between and the new one I tried with no space gave the results. thanks for your support and help in fixing the issue. appreciate it very much.

Comment: I'suggest you try to add a custom field to one of your account using the normal gmail interface, a simple one... just for test. maybe even on another account if you have one. I guess the issue comes from the custom field itself, Could there be a 'space' somewhere you don't see? I don't know but there must be something wrong somewhere since on my 2 accounts it gives predicted results.

Comment: hey ! we crossed our messages ! fortunately we came both to the same conclusion ! case closed then ;-) you can mark this post as answered ? thx

Comment: Serge, yes if you see the title of this post, you can know the custom field name that I am trying to get the results from, the Field name "Organization ID” has a space in it, which was causing the trouble. but still your EDIT-1 function is not working, I will further analyze on this and post my observations over the thread

Comment: these experiments have caused some very annoying bugs in 2 of my accounts ;-// it has (I don't know yet how) create nearly 25000 duplicate contacts in my contact list ... did you have this kind of issue too ?